# Swift UIActionSheet: Adding a second line of text and a Button

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I am looking to add a second line of text in smaller size to each of my ActionSheet actions. I am not able to get a second line of text using `\n`

Additionally, I want to have a button on the right hand side of each action.

How can I achieve this?

```
let playMenu = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let Action1 = UIAlertAction(title: button1, style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.playRecording(num)
        })

        let Action2 = UIAlertAction(title: button2, style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.shareRecording()
        })

        let Action3 = UIAlertAction(title: button3, style: .Destructive, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.deleteRecording()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButton, style: .Cancel, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            println("Cancelled")
        })


        playMenu.addAction(Action1)
        playMenu.addAction(Action2)
        playMenu.addAction(Action3)
        playMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        playMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        playMenu.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.height, 1.0, 1.0)

        self.presentViewController(playMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: can you show me your code

Comment: you can try this for break line var msg = "hello" + "\n" + "How are you"

Comment: \n doesnt work in this situation